# Reordenar ID em tabela após Deletar ou Inserir

Tags: php

Tenho uma tabela com uma coluna chamada `ID`. Esse `ID` não é Auto Increment nem é chave primária, mas segue uma sequencia numérica (ex: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...).

Preciso que ao **incluir** ou ao **deletar** em uma posição variável, recalculasse os IDs e fizesse o `update`. Exemplo:

- se DELETAR o ID 2, aos próximos IDs subtrai-se 1. Onde o `3` vira o `2`, `4` vira `3`, etc.

A mesma coisa ao INCLUIR em uma posição variável. Alguma idéa de como fazer?

Comment: Poderia traduzir a pergunta para o português?

Comment: mike, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Traduza a pergunta para o Português ela será reaberta. Abraço.

Comment: Qual bando de dados?

Comment: Para quê isso? Vai incluir uma complexidade desnecessária em seu aplicativo. Pense no custo em mover, digamos, 10 milhões de registros várias vezes ao dia por conta disso.

Comment: @mike você poderia justificar esse comportamento para que possamos te ajudar ?

Comment: Esta tabela é chave estrangeira em alguma outra tabela !? Reordenar faria perder o vínculo. Existe algum motivo forte para não ter "banguelas" nesta tabela ? Fora isto creio ser muito trabalho por nada.

Answer (score 1):

Quando algo começa torto tarde ou nunca de endireita. Eu faria asim:
- reorganizava a tabela, deixava os ID certos. Não é dificil, mas pode demorar  ou gastar muitos recursos

```
select id from table
$n=1;
while($row=fetch)
{
   UPDATE table SET id=$n WHERE id = $row[id];
   $n++;
}
```

- em vez de delete, quando para tirar algum registo, eu faria um update na linha, deixava todas as colunas em branco, menos a ID que ficava com o valor original.
- quando fosse necessário inserir um valor, procurava o ID mais baixo disponivel. Se não houvesse disponivel criava uma nova linha.

Depois fica mais facil de manter. Se começar a ter muitas linhas vazias, preenche estas linhas com as ultimas entradas e apagas as ultimas entradas.

Answer (score 0):

Com base na resposta acima (ou abaixo) que possivelmente será excluída ou incorporada ao tópico inicial na qual você diz ter intenção de recriar esse banco de dados um dia, creio que o motivo seja mais cosmético.

Assim sendo, como também acredito que você não deva ter uma fragmentação tão grande quanto parece ter hoje em intervalos curtos de tempo então, para reordenar tudo de uma vez, simplesmente delete a coluna da chave primária e recrie-a.

Mas é extremamente importante que, desde já, você se acostume com o fato de que seus IDs não irão sempre ser sequenciais.